# I want to convert a nested list it into a simple list in python

Tags: python

I want to convert

```
[('23.758481',), ('23.761419',), ('23.762254',)]
```

into

```
[ 23.75848,23.761419,23.762255]
```

in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If:

```
l = [('23.758481',), ('23.761419',), ('23.762254',)]
```

you could do:

```
[float(i[0]) for i in l]
```

this gives:

```
[23.758481, 23.761419, 23.762254]
```

what we do here is that, we take the first elements out of the tuples.

Or we could use `extend()`:

```
res = []
[res.extend(i) for i in l]
```